# How to find empty tables with classname using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a page which is generating html tables dynamically. I do not have any control as to how the tables are being generated but I can put JavaScript code in it.

What I am trying to do is that there are some tables which are empty i.e. they have only `<th>` row and no `<td>` rows. I want to hide / remove those tables using JavaScript.

All the tables have a class "card-table".

Is it possible to find all the tables with "card-table" class and if has less than 1 row then remove/hide it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I'm just trying using jQuery or JavaScript but I'm not sure how to traverse the tables using same class and remove / hide them.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: `$('.card-table').each(...)` to loop over the tables. Inside the callback function, use `find` to find the `tr` contained within the current table element, and check the `length` of what's returned. If 0, hide the current table.

Comment: *they have only row and no rows* Huh?

Comment: "*Yes. It is possible.*" - protip: always ask the question you want the answer to.

Comment: @connexo classic case of markup not escaped.  Not sure "only th row and no td rows" is technically correct, but it gives the idea that there's only a "header" row.  OP likely doesn't distinguish between `thead` and `tbody` and doesn't realise `th` can be mixed with `td` within the same `tr` in `tbody`.  Including relevant HTML would help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.card-table').each(function() {
        // If the table has less than 2 rows, hide it
        if ($(this).find('tr').length < 2) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Kikloo please remember to mark as answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Not showing tables with zero rows

```js
$(function() {
  $('table.card-table').each(function() {
    const $rows = $(this).find('tr');
    $(this).toggle($rows.length > 0); // show if more than 0
  });
});
```

Vanilla

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('table.card-table').forEach(table => {
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    table.hidden = rows.length === 0; // hide if 0
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables have a built-in API for accessing and counting `rows` and `columns`, and also for `tBodies`. This also takes into account that your empty table might have a non-empty `thead` labelling your empty columns.

Use it:

```js
for (const table of document.querySelectorAll('table.card-table')) {
  table.hidden = [...table.tBodies].every(body => body.rows.length === 0);
}
```

Make sure to properly run this code when you're certain all tables in question are properly parsed in the document, e.g. by running it inside a `DOMContentLoaded` listener.

**That being said, it would be highly preferrable to not render these tables in the first place. So I'd strongly suggest to fix this in the part of the code, that generates the tables.**